# How to automatically set indent width (e.g. c-basic-offset) based on edited file?

Tags: indentation

I often work on several different codebases that use different indent styles (2 spaces vs 4 spacces vs tabs...). It is annoying to set `c-basic-offset` (or other variables, depending on mode) each time I open new file. Is there a package (or setting) that makes Emacs detect indentation style of opened file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out dtrt-indent on melpa.

Answer (score 4):

CC-mode comes with the `cc-guess.el` file which provides functions to do that.

E.g. `M-x c-guess` should do the trick.

Comment: Works well, but guessing takes several minute for bigger files.

Comment: I think the docstring you get from `C-h f c-guess RET` should give you some hints about how to control its run-time, eg.g. by restricting the part of the file it scans.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that for a specific file is to use [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables):

> A file can specify local variable values to use when editing the file
>   with Emacs.  Visiting the file checks for local variable specifications;
>   it automatically makes these variables local to the buffer, and sets
>   them to the values specified in the file.

The doc describes how you can specify them in a comment on the first line of the file, or as a “local variables list” near the end of the file.

For a whole code base, using [Per-Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) is certainly more appropriate.

> Sometimes, you may wish to define the same set of local variables to all
>   the files in a certain directory and its subdirectories, such as the
>   directory tree of a large software project.  This can be accomplished
>   with “directory-local variables”.

Again, the linked doc (or info doc from within emacs) describes how to define them.